# Same object being only queryable in some situations while fully editable in other situations

Tags: c#

In some situations, I only want the client code to query an object and prevent modification to it, in other cases the client can query and modify it.

I thought I could control it by returning the object in an interface type with only querying methods, but the client code can still cast it in the "editable" interface, so it does not really prevent anything.

For example:

```
interface IProductDescription  //Read-only interface
{
    string Name {get;}
    double CalculatePrice();
}

interface IProduct : IProductDescription  //Editable interface
{
    string Name {get; set;}
    void ChangePrice(double newPrice);
}

class ProductX : IProduct
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public double CalculatePrice()
    {
       //Do some business code and return a price
    }

    public void ChangePrice(double newPrice)
    {
        //update product price
    }
}
```

Client code:

```
IProductDescription product = myInventory.GetProductDescription("X");

((IProduct)product).ChangePrice(999);
```

Now the problem I have is that even if I return the object to client code into an IProductDescription type, it can't call the ChangePrice method as is, but it is very easy to just cast it in the IProduct type and then call ChangePrice.

How could I achieve this ? 
Or am I just too paranoid and I should leave the method accessible to the client code and "tell+hope" the method is only used when it is allowed ?, but that does not seem very good to me...

Comment: Are the consumers you want to prevent modifications from validly allowed to use an `IProduct` elsewhere?  IE do they need to be aware of its existence?

Comment: The querying service won't need to know anything about `IProduct`. You mean that I should place it in a different library and don't reference it from the querying service ?

Comment: If you're able to structure your libraries that way, yes - keep it private or internal.  People could still get to it through reflection, but at that point all bets are off.

Comment: Maybe I'll try that... So far I always worked with very small c# projects so I didn't need to do this, but this one is bigger and I'm wondering is it a common practice to prevent some methods to be called on objects like this depending on the situation or people usually just assume it won't be called ?

It is also a question of concurrency, if many users are sharing a same queryable object, I don't want it to be modified because it could lead to many problems.